# How do I insert elements into an array C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to programming and for one of my college classes I have to use C#. I'm not super familiar with C# and I am having trouble with my assignment. And unfortunatly I've spent a little over an hour trying to find solutions. And my search has come up empty. No one I know understands or can code anything. Plz Help

> Under the Main method, create an array named as n of 10 integers.
>
> Create a for loop to assign the value to the n array from 100 to 109.
>
> Create a foreach loop to output each array element's value.

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int[] n = new int[10];

         for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
                 n[i] = 100 + i;
         }

         foreach (int i in n)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(int[i]);
         }
     }
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/S6Wbny

Comment: In your last `foreach` you need to output `i` not `int[i]`. `i` in that loop is the value in the `n` array e.g. `Console.WriteLine(i);`

Comment: @MichaelRandall snap - https://dotnetfiddle.net/hbPQ70

Comment: @stuartd hah, neither of us pressed tidy

Comment: Hey so now that I have replaced the `int[i]` with an `i`. It runs. But the website is saying that it is incorrect. Any idea why?

Comment: "*But the website is saying that it is incorrect*" we cant read the websites mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *almost* perfect for the assignment

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create an array named as n of 10 integers
    int[] n = new int[10];

    // create a for loop to assign the value to the n array from 100 to 109.
    for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        n[i] = 100 + i;
    }
    // create a foreach loop to output each array element's value.
    foreach (int item in n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

as you can see, in your code `i` is an integer from the array element, and not the array index. So your `int[i]` is incorrect syntax.

Comment: What was wrong with the code that made it almost perfect?

Comment: @Enigmativity Don't know, somebody is downvoting two answers here.

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
Console.WriteLine(int[i]);
```

Must be replaced with this:

```
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a few alternatives as well as a solution to your immediate challenge.
In `int[i]` you wrote down the data type `int` instead of the name of the array, which is `n`. when `i` is a valid index `n[i]` gives you the value. in a `foreach` construct you give the value a name to be used in each iteration. confusingly you named it `i` as well, so `i` gives you the value. `i` is common in `for` loops as the index so this may be confused with that idiom and you would be better off using a more speaking name like `number` in your code.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Implementation1();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Implementation2();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Implementation3();
    }
    static void Implementation1()
    {
        int[] n = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; ++i)
            n[i] = 100 + i;
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; ++i)
            Console.WriteLine(n[i]);
    }
    static void Implementation2()
    {
        int[] n = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; ++i)
            n[i] = 100 + i;
        foreach (var number in n)
            Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
    static void Implementation3()
    {
        var n = Enumerable.Range(100, 10).ToArray();
        string.Join(',', n.Select(val => $"{val}"));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', n.Select(val => $"{val}")));
    }
}
```